# How to limit about of items returned in XML feed using Jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, xml

I don't have control over the returned XML feed, **so i was wondering how I could limit the amount of items returned**.

I need help structuring the ***for loop***, assuming that's the best approach for my goal.

Currently, my code looks like this:

> HTML:

```
<div id="results"></div>
```

> AJAX Get request to PHP file to convert XML to string:

```
$.get('mydomainhere/feed.php', {}, showPosts);

function showPosts(data){
    var posts = $(data).find('channel>item');
    var str = "<ul>";
        $.each(posts,function(index,value){
            var title = $(value).find('title').text();
            var description = $(value).find('description').text();
            str+= "<li>";
            str+= "<div>";
            str+= "<h3>" + title + "</h3>";
            str+= "<p>" + description + "</p>";
            str+= "</div>";
            str+= "</li>";
        });

    str+= "</ul>";
    $('#results').html(str);
};
```

> The PHP feed file:

```
<?php $feedData = file_get_contents('xml-test.xml'); echo $feedData; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
function showPosts(data){
    var limit = 10;
    var posts = $(data).find('channel>item');
    var str = "<ul>";
        $.each(posts,function(index,value){
            if(index >= limit) { return false; }
            var title = $(value).find('title').text();
            var description = $(value).find('description').text();
            str+= "<li>";
            str+= "<div>";
            str+= "<h3>" + title + "</h3>";
            str+= "<p>" + description + "</p>";
            str+= "</div>";
            str+= "</li>";
        });

    str+= "</ul>";
    $('#results').html(str);
};
```

Comment: Thank you. That looks like it should work. I'll test later today and report back.